# How to grep strings like this?

Tags: linux, unix, text, grep, find

strings:

```
4b30a444-86c9-4fb8-b5dc-ba721e30fb24    
a8e4e6a8-5655-4adc-a393-ccbb6848c9dc
cc1918be-a532-4ebe-948a-de78cc455fcb
12b6e407-4ec0-4cc6-80d4-b38d7df99694
5b153e1f-6abd-4fd9-9ce2-c7917010f3ee
```

I tried these:

```
egrep [a-z0-9]-[a-z0-9]-[a-z0-9]-[a-z0-9]-[a-z0-9]

egrep '[a-z]{2,}-[a-z]{2,}-[a-z]{2,}-[a-z]{2,}-[a-z]{2,}'

egrep '.-.-.-.-.'
```

But nothing happened

Comment: It's always easy to write a regexp that matches the strings you want to find but **much** harder to write one that doesn't additionally match other strings you don't want (e.g. `.*` matches everything in your question but also would match anything else) so edit your question to include not just the strings you want to match but the context they appear in in your input so we can help you come up with a robust solution rather than one that will produce the output you expect today and then fail tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

use `+` for 1 or more chars of that character class like this:

```
$ egrep '[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+' data 
4b30a444-86c9-4fb8-b5dc-ba721e30fb24    
a8e4e6a8-5655-4adc-a393-ccbb6848c9dc
cc1918be-a532-4ebe-948a-de78cc455fcb
12b6e407-4ec0-4cc6-80d4-b38d7df99694
5b153e1f-6abd-4fd9-9ce2-c7917010f3ee
$
```

or use fixed number of chars using quantifiers like this:

```
$ egrep '[a-z0-9]{8}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{4}-[a-z0-9]{12}' data 
4b30a444-86c9-4fb8-b5dc-ba721e30fb24    
a8e4e6a8-5655-4adc-a393-ccbb6848c9dc
cc1918be-a532-4ebe-948a-de78cc455fcb
12b6e407-4ec0-4cc6-80d4-b38d7df99694
5b153e1f-6abd-4fd9-9ce2-c7917010f3ee
```

or you can use `{2,}` for 2 or more chars like this:

```
$ egrep '[a-z0-9]{2,}-[a-z0-9]{2,}-[a-z0-9]{2,}-[a-z0-9]{2,}-[a-z0-9]{2,}' data 
4b30a444-86c9-4fb8-b5dc-ba721e30fb24    
a8e4e6a8-5655-4adc-a393-ccbb6848c9dc
cc1918be-a532-4ebe-948a-de78cc455fcb
12b6e407-4ec0-4cc6-80d4-b38d7df99694
5b153e1f-6abd-4fd9-9ce2-c7917010f3ee
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Perl-style regular expression, because it's much closer to the expressions we used to use in programming languages:

```bash
c='[a-z0-9]'
grep -P "$c{8}(?:-$c{4}){3}-$c{12}" input.txt
```

Here we save repeated sequence into `$c` shell variable.

- `-P` instructs `grep` to use Perl style
- `{N}` repeats previous expression `N` times
- `(?:)` creates non-capturing group for efficiency(we might use just `()` instead)
- `(?:...){3}` repeats contents of the group 3 times

Comment: While this answer provides a solution, it provides no explanation. Ruslan, can you add some detail to explain why this works, and why you think this solution is best compared to other options?

Comment: Description added.

Comment: Thanks. Alas, with the addition of Perl-style I again can't upvote, as it makes your answer non-portable.  (BSD and OSX don't have `-P`.)